# Hide long text in table but keep access to it

Tags: user-expectation, tables, interface

I'm trying to cut a long text in a `<td>` but keep access to the data inside it. Maybe like on mobile by clicking and dragging inside the area.

I've done a post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52271519/5003342) for more details.

[image]

---

I didn't find any good **UX** alternative if I want to keep a fixed width in my `<td>`. Any ideas of what can be achieved ? Is it a good way to do it ?

Any live examples on how some websites deals with that ?

Comment: Have you considered simply continuing the text on a new line?

Comment: @Levano Yes but I don't want to break the layout, I want to keep it as in the example

Answer (score 1):

Add ellipsis and show full text on mouse hover.

**Example: ux.stackexchange profile page**

[image]

If you need to perform some actions with the text, you can use an interactive tooltip.

**Example: [IBM's Interactive tooltip](http://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/tooltip/usage#interactive-tooltip)**

[image]

Comment: I was about to suggest the same solution. Since the OP is having problems with path that is too long to fit, perhaps the field content should be the file name only with leading dots, like `...\filename.txt` and the balloon text could contain the full path.

Comment: Agree, good point!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of data, I see an additional few options:

- Display full contents on hover (if data need only be read).
- Displaying the data in a popout/dropdown with additional controls (e.g. a copy to clipboard button) if needed.

The scrollbar may still be appropriate, or used in conjunction with other solutions.